# Meniscus outside of a cylinder - axisymmetric Young-Laplace equation in semi-infinite domain

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, boundary-condition-at-infinity, axisymmetry

How to solve the axisymmetric Young-Laplace equation

$$\frac{z'(r)}{r \sqrt{z'(r)^2+1}}+\frac{z''(r)}{\left(z'(r)^2+1\right)^{3/2}}=z(r)$$

with b.c.s

$$z'(1)=-2$$$$z'(\infty)=0$$

where $z=Z/l_c$ and $r=R/l_c$ are dimensionless height and radius, $Z$, $R$ are the corresponding real height and radius, $l_c=\sqrt{\frac{\gamma }{g \rho }}$ is capillary length, $\gamma$ is surface tension, $g$ is the acceleration of gravity and $\rho$ is the density difference between phases. The solution of the problem describes the shape of meniscus outside of a cylinder, how can I obtain it with `NDSolve`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ## Note
>
> Because of [an arguable backslide around
>   *v11*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/110626/ndsz-step-size-is-effectively-zero-singularity-or-stiff-system-suspected/130373#comment399158_130373),
>   the code pieces for `sol1` and `sol3` are broken since then. I haven't yet
>   found a easy workaround.
>
> Luckily, core parts of this answer i.e. those about `solnew` are not influenced.

The most direct solution for the problem seems to be approximating the b.c. at infinity with a b.c. that's just far enough e.g.

$$z'(10)\approx z'(\infty)=0$$

and it's indeed applicable:

```
eq = z''[r]/(1 + z'[r]^2)^(3/2) + z'[r]/(r (Sqrt[1 + z'[r]^2])) == z[r];

{lb, rb} = {1, 10};
bcl = z'[lb] == -2;
bcr := z'[rb] == 0;

sol1 = NDSolveValue[{eq, bcl, bcr}, z, {r, lb, rb}];

Plot[sol1[r], {r, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

However, this approach isn't that stable. Though the value of `rb` is an approximation of infinity, it turns out that the solution will go wild if we set `rb` a little larger:

```
rb = 20;
sol2 = NDSolveValue[{eq, bcl, bcr}, z, {r, lb, rb}];
Plot[sol2[r], {r, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

One can relieve the problem by manually setting a better initial guess and sub-method (by trial and error) to `"Shooting"` method:

```
sol3 = NDSolveValue[{eq, bcl, bcr}, z, {r, lb, rb}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {bcr, z[rb] == 0}, 
    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"}]
Plot[sol3[r], {r, lb, rb}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

But is there a better approach?

The answer is yes.

The key point is to use the asymptotic solution at far field (not sure if I've used the correct terminology) as the b.c. instead of that at infinity. (I found this technique in [Huh, Chun, and L. E. Scriven. "Shapes of axisymmetric fluid interfaces of unbounded extent." Journal of Colloid and Interface Science 30.3 (1969): 323-337.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021979769903993) but it's probably not the only place the technique is mentioned.)

Since $z(r)\to 0$ when $r$ is large enough, we have

```
Series[1/Sqrt[1 + z'[r]^2]^3, {z'[r], 0, 5}]
Series[1/Sqrt[1 + z'[r]^2], {z'[r], 0, 5}]
```

$$\frac{1}{(\sqrt{z'(r)^2+1})^3}= 1-\frac{3}{2} z'(r)^2+\frac{15}{8} z'(r)^4+O(z'(r)^6)$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{z'(r)^2+1}}=1-\frac{1}{2} z'(r)^2+\frac{3}{8} z'(r)^4+O(z'(r)^6)$$

Neglecting high order terms, we deduce the asymptotic equation in the outer zone:

```
eqOuter = z''[r] + z'[r]/r - z[r] == 0;
```

Solve `eqOuter` with b.c. at infinity:

```
generalOuter[c_, r_] = 
 FullSimplify[
   Limit[DSolve[{eqOuter, z'[rInf] == 0}, z, r][[1, 1, -1]][r], rInf -> ∞], 
   r > 0] /. C[1] -> -c Pi/2 I

particularOuter[r_, rMiddle_, tanMiddle_] = 
 generalOuter[c, r] /. 
  Solve[Derivative[0, 1][generalOuter][c, rMiddle] == tanMiddle, c][[1]]
```

Now we get the new right boundary:

```
newbcr := z[rb] == particularOuter[rb, rb, z'[rb]];
```

Notice though `particularOuter` is a asymptotic solution, as `r` increases, it becomes prominent **very fast** i.e. we can obtain a good enough solution without a very large `rb`:

```
rb = 2;
solnew = NDSolveValue[{eq, bcl, newbcr}, z, {r, lb, rb}]

Show[Plot[particularOuter[r, rb, solnew'[rb]], {r, rb, 10}, PlotRange -> All], 
 Plot[solnew[r], {r, lb, rb}], AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}]
```

[image]

*Can you tell the value of `rb` only by checking the graph :D?*