# ndsz : step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

This is the first time I ask a question. I have seen many solutions to this error and tried but they are not working.

Here is the code.

```
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"];
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
Needs["FunctionApproximations`"];

Clear["Global`*"];

e = 1.60217662*10^-19;
c = 299792458;
m = 9.10938356*10^-31;
ϵ0 = 8.854187817*10^-12;
A = 10^17;
h = 6.62607004*10^-34; hbar = 1.0545718*10^-34;
k = 1/ϵ0 (2 e/h^3) (4 Pi/3);
x0 = (3/(4 *Pi)*A*1.60439572*10^-24/(4*10^14))^(1/3)/100;

xf = 10^0;

s = NDSolve[{1/x D[x y[x], {x, 2}] == 
    k ((e y[x]/c)^2 + 2 m*e y[x])^1.5, y[x0] == 10^6, y[xf] == 10^-5},
   y[x], {x, x0, xf}]
```

`xf` should be infinity but `NDSolve` doesn't allow infinity so I put a relatively large number.

`y[xf]` is also needed to be zero at infinity. I put a relatively small number since I expected that `y[x]` is close to zero when x is approaching infinity.

Here is the error:

> At x == 0.112455460174063`, step size is effectively zero; singularity
>   or stiff system suspected. >>

Comment: Please format the code in your question using code blocks. Take a look at this as well: [How to copy code from *Mathematica* so it looks good on this site](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951).

Comment: Have you seen any other examples of using a large number instead of infinity at the singular point? Because by definition boundary condition at singularity is very tricky. If you have, I'd appreciate it if you could share.

Answer (score 6):

> ## Note
>
> Because of an arguable backslide around *v11*, the solution in this answer doesn't work since then. See comments below for more information.

According to my personal experience, when approximating boundary condition (b.c.) at infinity with a b.c. at a large distance, usually the *large distance* should not be too large, and when solving nonlinear boundary value problem, manual setting a good enough initial guess for shooting method is often necessary. Your problem fits well in these rules:

```
e = 1.60217662*10^-19;
c = 299792458;
m = 9.10938356*10^-31;
ϵ0 = 8.854187817*10^-12;
A = 10^17;
h = 6.62607004*10^-34; hbar = 1.0545718*10^-34;
k = 1/ϵ0 (2 e/h^3) (4 Pi/3);
x0 = (3/(4*Pi)*A*1.60439572*10^-24/(4*10^14))^(1/3)/100;

xf = 50 10^-10;

sol = NDSolve[{1/x D[x y[x], {x, 2}] == k ((e y[x]/c)^2 + 2 m*e y[x])^1.5, y[x0] == 10^6, 
   y[xf] == 0}, y, {x, x0, xf}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y[xf] == 0, y'[xf] == 0}}]

Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, x0, xf}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

The following is a comparision between the solution given by bbgodfrey and me. As one can see, the 2 solutions are fairly consistent:

```
bbgodfreyplot = LogPlot[{yn[r2000, 45][xn] /. s, 144/xn^4} // Evaluate, {xn, x0n, xfn}, 
       AxesLabel -> {"x/xs", "y/ys"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 11], 
   PlotRange -> All];
  
xzczdplot = 
 Unevaluated@
   LogPlot[y[x xs]/ys /. sol, {x, x0/xs, xf/xs}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed, Thick}] /. norms;

Show[xzczdplot, bbgodfreyplot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `NDSolve` returns unevaluated, when I run your code.  I am using 11.1.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: @bbgodfrey So we found another backslide… The code works well in v9.0.1 on Win10.

Comment: That is what I feared.  I hope that you report it to Wolfram, Inc.  Best wishes.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Response from WRI: "Thank you for contacting Wolfram Technical Support. I understand that for the example in the notebook you sent in, NDSolve evaluates in version 9, but no longer evaluates in version 11. It appears that the result returned in version 9 does not satisfy the equation. To prevent returning a wrong result, between version 9 and 11 more stringent error checks must have put in place so that NDSolve would return unevaluated instead of returning a wrong result in cases like this. "…

Comment: …Then in the attachment of the response the following code is used to check the error: `Plot[eqn[[1]] /. s // Evaluate, {x, x0, xf}]`, it does show a large error, but… I should say I feel bit unconvinced about this response, because I roughly remember, there exists example indicating that, checking error in this way may be too rigorous for nonlinear ODEs, but I can't find it at moment so can't launch an effective "counterattack"…

Comment: It might be useful to compare your "Shooting" answer with the one I just posted to see whether the claim by Wolfram, Inc that the former method involved too large an error for this problem is accurate.  I cannot make the comparison myself, because I do not have version 9 of Mathematica.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The 2 solutions are (acceptably) consistent, see my update. OK, time to write back to WRI.

Comment: Informative comparison (+1).  It prompted me to run your code again, but this time with my renormalized ODE.  Instead of returning unevaluated, it failed with the all too common zero step-size error, even when I used the separatrix solution as the boundary condition and initial guess at `xfn`..

Answer (score 6):

**Analysis of the equation**

It often is convenient to non-dimensionalize ODEs arising in physics, and this case is no exception.  Rescale `x` and `y` by `{x -> xn xs, y[x] -> yn[xn] ys}`.  Apply these transformations to the ODE, bringing the scale factors from the left side of the ODE, `(xs^2/ys)`, to the right.

```
eqlast = (xs^2/ys) k ((e y[x]/c)^2 + 2 m*e y[x])^(3/2) /. 
    y[x] -> yn[t] ys /. x -> xn xs /. t -> xn
(* (k xs^2 (2 e m ys yn[xn] + (e^2 ys^2 yn[xn]^2)/c^2)^(3/2))/ys *)
```

Now, choose the scale factors, `xs` and `ys`, to eliminate the multipliers of `yn[xn]` and `yn[xn]^2`.

```
eq1 = eqlast[[1 ;; 3]] (eqlast[[4, 1, 1]])^(3/2) /. yn[xn] -> 1 /. xn -> 1
(* (2 Sqrt[2] k xs^2 (e m ys)^(3/2))/ys *)
eq2 = eqlast[[1 ;; 3]] (eqlast[[4, 1, 2]])^(3/2) /. yn[xn] -> 1 /. xn -> 1
(* (k xs^2 ((e^2 ys^2)/c^2)^(3/2))/ys *)
norms = FullSimplify[Solve[eq1 == 1 && eq2 == 1 && k > 0 && e > 0 && m > 0 && c > 0, 
    {xs, ys}, Reals], k > 0 && e > 0 && m > 0 && c > 0] // Last
(* {xs -> Sqrt[1/(c e k)]/(2 m), ys -> (2 c^2 m)/e} *)
```

Inserting these expressions into the transformed ODE yields,

```
eq = 1/xn D[xn yn[xn], {xn, 2}] == Simplify[eqlast /. %, k > 0 && e > 0 && m > 0 && c > 0]
(* (2 yn'[xn] + xn yn''[xn])/xn == (yn[xn] (1 + yn[xn]))^(3/2) *)
```

which is somewhat easier to work with than the ODE in its original form.  The question seeks a solution with very small `y` at large `x`.  To obtain such an asymptotic solution, assume that `y^2` is much smaller than `y` (in absolute value).  Then, it is apparent that a solution exists equal to `cf xn^a`, `a` and `cf` constants.

```
Unevaluated[1/xn D[xn yn[xn], {xn, 2}] - (yn[xn] (1 + yn[xn]))^(3/2)] /. 
    {(1 + yn[xn]) -> 1, yn[xn] -> cf xn^a}
(* a (1 + a) cf xn^(-2 + a) - (cf xn^a)^(3/2) *)
```

For this expression to vanish, xn^(-2 + a) == xn^(3 a/2) clearly is required.  In other words, `a == -4`.  Then, `cf` is determined from

```
Simplify[% /. a -> -4, cf > 0 && xn > 0]
(* -(((-12 + Sqrt[cf]) cf)/xn^6) *)
```

So, `cf == 144`, and this particular solution is `yn[xn] == 144/xn^4`.  As we shall see, this is not the most general solution at large `xn`, but it does appear to be a separatrix.

**Numerical Solution**

With the constants given in the question, the scale factors become,

```
norms
(* {xs -> 3.46944*10^-12, ys -> 1.022*10^6} *)
```

and the starting point of the integration, `x0`, normalized to `xs`, becomes (rationalized for future use in `NDSolve`)

```
x0n = Rationalize[x0/xs /. norms, 0]
(* 723020393/5483051 *)
```

or about `131.865`, and the specified value of `y[x0]`, normalized to `ys`, becomes

```
y0n = Rationalize[10^6/ys /. norms, 0]
(* 33547031/34284995 *)
```

or about `0.978476`.  Conveniently, `x0n` is well away from the singularity at `xn == 0`.  The problem, now, is to choose `yn'[x0n]` to that `yn[xn]` approaches the separatrix, obtained above, at large `xn`.  Employing a variant on the method employed to solve question [147207](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147585/1063) yields the desired value of `yn'[x0n]`.

```
xfn = 2000;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{eq, yn[x0n] == y0n, yn'[x0n] == yp0, 
    WhenEvent[Re@yn[xn] < 120/xfn^4 || yn'[xn] > 1/100, "StopIntegration"]}, 
    yn, {xn, x0n, xfn}, {yp0, wp}, WorkingPrecision -> wp, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
    MaxSteps -> 20000];
```

`WhenEvent[ ... ]` is used here to terminate integration, whenever a numerical solution veers away from the separatrix.  Doing so is desirable, because one hundred or more iterations at high `WorkingPrecision` typically are needed to obtain a desired solution.  A small amount of experimentation is sufficient to determine that the initial value for `yn'[x0n]` is near `-1.39`.  A better approximation then is obtained from

```
plt = Plot[Quiet@(yn[yp0, 15]["Domain"] /. s)[[1, 2]], {yp0, -1.306, -1.304}, 
    PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

The improved estimate, given by the spike in the plot, is located within the range,

```
Cases[plt, Line[a__] :> a, Infinity] // Last;
Position[%, Max[Last /@ %]][[1, 1]];
est = SetPrecision[{First[%%[[% - 1]]], First[%%[[% + 1]]]}, 45]
(* {-1.30493508434085847547123648837441578507423401, 
    -1.30493385315771526222761167446151375770568848} *)
```

This already narrow range is reduced much further with

```
dom[yp0_?NumericQ] := Quiet@(yn[yp0, 45]["Domain"] /. s)[[1, 2]] 
gg[bl0_, bu0_] := Module[{bl = N[bl0, 45], bu = N[bu0, 45], bt, db}, 
    Do[bt = (bl + bu)/2; db = (bu - bl)/100; 
    If[dom[bt] - dom[bt - db] > 0, bl = bt, bu = bt], {i, 120}]; bt];
```

(Note that `FixedPoint` could be used here instead of `Do` but appears to offer no advantage, at least for the present computation.)

```
r2000 = gg @@ est
(yn[r2000, 45][xfn] /. s) - 120/xfn^4
(* -1.30493476864289837272478679314595905244023206 *)
(* 8.3663144286145423790813208786836901834*10^-17 *)
```

About `80 sec` was used by my PC to obtain this result.  Such very high precision usually is necessary when seeking a solution asymptotically approaching a separatrix.  Below is a plot of the numerical result, in blue, and the separatrix, in orange.

```
LogPlot[{yn[r2000, 45][xn] /. s, 144/xn^4}, {xn, x0n, xfn}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"x/xs", "y/ys"}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, 11], PlotRange -> All]
```

As expected (and desired), the numerical solution is quite near the separatrix at large `xn`, even when viewed on a log plot.

[image]