# How can I make NDSolve in version 11 use the same methods as version 9?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, version-9, version-11

Sorry for the lack of a minimal working example but the code I am concerned about is rather large and I have no idea what the problem is. All I know is that when I run the code in Mathematica versions 9, 10, 11, version 9 gives the correct result while versions 10 and 11 do not. There are no error messages. My best guess is that the problem is related to changes to NDSolve between the different versions since I have seen a similar problem before. However, with previous problems, I was able to stumble across a fix by playing with different choices for Method. This time I am having no such luck.

So my question is, is there a way to force NDSolve in version 11 to work precisely like the default settings of version 9?

Comment: [related](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140773/5467). Finite Element Method only appeared with wersion 10 of Mathematica.

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem has anything to do with [this rather interesting discussion about why GiNaC was developed](https://www.ginac.de/FAQ.html#whynotmaple)

Comment: An possible explanation, but not a solution, to your issue can be found in the comments following the first answer to [130373](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130373/1063).  I ran into a similar problem [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/151089/1063).

Comment: (continuation of my first comment) :  does your code try to use Finite Element Method when you are on Mathematica 10 or 11 ? If yes, you should impose the TensorProductGrid Method.

Comment: @andre I'm struggling to digest the discussion you linked to. How can I find out if the code is trying to use Finite Element Method? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you give all the arguments, except the first one, you use when you invoque `NDSolve` ?

Comment: NDSolve[eqlist, params, {t, tstart, tend}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 13, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
   Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Solve"}]; This choice of Method solved a previous problem I had when changing from version 9 to version 10. In this case though, commenting it out or not has no effect.

Comment: Thanks. Surprise ! Your are dealing with ODEs , not PDEs. So all what I said is irrelevant (!)