# Overflow with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, finite-element-method, backslide

**Backslide introduced in 10.0, persisting through 12.1.**

---

I am trying to solve the following differential equation and plot the result:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
rin = 10^-30;
sol = NDSolve[{Sqrt[x] D[χ[x], {x, 2}] == χ[x]^(3/2), χ[rin] == 1, χ[10] == 0}, χ, {x, rin, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 20,Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"]
Chi[x_] := χ[x] /. sol[[1]]
Plot[Chi[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

but I get the errors

> General::ovfl: Overflow occurred in computation.
>
> NDSolve::ndsz: At x== 5.44548672805763394929852270934792356776`20., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

**EDIT** I use version 10.0

Comment: Just tested in _v9.0.1_, and `NDSolve` works without any adjustion. So the underlying issue seems to be the backslide mentioned here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130373/1871

Comment: @xzczd ok thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd like to extend my comments to an answer. For those in *v12* or higher, `FiniteElement` is a possible choice for this problem, as shown in [user21's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219608/1871). But, if you're in a version lower than *v12* but higher than *v9*, it becomes a bit more troublesome, because

1. nonlinear `FiniteElement` isn't implemented yet.
2. `Shooting` method can't handle the problem well, which is [an arguable backslide](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130373/1871).

[image]

*As we can see, though `ndsz` warning is generated, `NDSolve` manages to find the desired result in v9.*

OK, so what to do? Well, to be honest I don't know if the following solution will cause other problem in *v10.0*, because *v10.0* is a quite unstable version, but it does work in *v9* and *v12.1*:

```
rin = 10^-30;

psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{D[χ[x], {x, 2}] == (χ[x]^(3/2))/Sqrt[x], χ'[
     10] == d, χ[10] == 0}, χ, {x, rin, 10}, d]

drule = FindRoot[psol[d][rin] == 1, {d, 0 (* choose -1/10 if in v9 *)}] // Quiet
(* {d -> -0.0116574} *)

Plot[psol[d /. drule][r] // Evaluate, {r, rin, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Alternatively, we can turn to finite difference method (FDM). I'll use [`pdetoae`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of finite difference equations:

```
rin = 0;

eq = D[χ[x], {x, 2}] Sqrt[x] == (χ[x]^(3/2));

bc = {χ[rin] == 1, χ[10] == 0};

points = 25; domain = {rin, 10}; grid = Array[# &, points, domain]; difforder = 2;

del = #[[2 ;; -2]] &;
(* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)    
ptoafunc = pdetoae[χ[x], grid, difforder];

ae = ptoafunc@eq // del;

initialguess[x_] = 0;

solrule = FindRoot[{ae, bc}, Table[{χ[x], initialguess[x]}, {x, grid}]]

sol = ListInterpolation[solrule[[All, -1]], grid]
```

Comment: I actually tried what you show at the very top as first thing. But it fails on V 12.1.  Not just warning, no result is given.  Screen shot. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/oFQcj.png) Strange it works in V 9

Comment: @Nasser Yeah, that's why I consider this as a backslide, sadly WRI doesn't think so. (See the discussion in comments in 2nd link for more info. )

Comment: I wonder how [Matlab's bvp](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bvp4c.html) numerical solver handles this.  May be I should try and find out sometime.

Comment: @xzczd There is a typo in your code it should be `D[χ[x], {x, 2}] == χ[x]^(3/2)/Sqrt[x]`

Comment: @Alex Oops… Fixed, thx for pointing out.

Comment: @xzczd Ok! Now we can compare two solutions. And as I can see, combination of `ParametricNDSolveValue[]` and `FindRoot[]` is still good.

Answer (score 10):

**Update:**

Alex noted a typo in my answer. Sorry about this. You can still solve this equation with the nonlinear FEM solver, thought it's not a as straight forward as for the miss typed equation.

Using

```
NDSolveValue[{D[\[Chi][x], {x, 2}] == \[Chi][x]^(3/2)/Sqrt[x], \[Chi][
    rin] == 1, \[Chi][10] == 0}, \[Chi], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Method -> "FiniteElement"]
```

gives an error message:

[image]

This is a fairly general failure message. The reason it is so general is that for the code it's impossible to say why it failed. One cause can the that there is a transition from the real to the complex plain. An easy way to try this is to either give an complex valued initial seed or, alternatively, to add a `0. I` complex component to the equation:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[\[Chi][x], {x, 2}] == \[Chi][x]^(3/2)/
      Sqrt[x], \[Chi][rin] == 1, \[Chi][10] == 0}, \[Chi], {x, 0, 10},
    Method -> "FiniteElement", InitialSeeding -> \[Chi][x] == 0. I];
Plot[Re[sol[x]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note the `Re` in the plot. Now, there is also a small complex component in the solution:

```
Plot[Im[sol[x]], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

But the solution compares favorably to other solutions presented here:

```
Plot[Evaluate[psol[d /. drule][r] - Re[sol[r]]], {r, rin, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Old answer:**

How about:

```
rin = 0;
sol = NDSolve[{D[\[Chi][x], {x, 2}] == (\[Chi][x]^3/2)/
      Sqrt[x] , \[Chi][rin] == 1, \[Chi][10] == 0}, \[Chi], {x, rin, 
    10}, Method -> "FiniteElement"];
Chi[x_] := Evaluate[\[Chi][x] /. sol[[1]]];
Plot[Chi[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

If you are interested in why I reformulated the equations then [this](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#588198981) section from the documentation is a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks I will read it!

Comment: I have just tried to run your code, but I get the error `NDSolve::femnonlinear: Nonlinear coefficients are not supported in this version of NDSolve` I use version 10.0

Comment: Also, after correcting the equation (it is `\[chi][x]^(3/2)`) I get the error `CoefficientArrays::poly: "-(\[Chi]^1.5/Sqrt[x])+\[Chi]$7768 is not a polynomial."`

Comment: @mattiav27 Nonlinear FEM is supported by `NDSolve` since _v12_. For earlier versions, playing with `Shooting` method should help, FDM is also a choice. For both methods we already have many related posts, just search in this site.

Comment: Although the plot looks reasonable (compare [219895](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219895/1063)), the first derivative is far from accurate near the origin without `Method -> {"FiniteElement", "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> .01}}` or finer. Using higher-order finite elements also might be helpful.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, you mean this: `s1 = Chi[x];
s2 = sol2[1][x];
Plot[Evaluate[{D[s1, x], D[s2, x]}], {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1.5}, {-0.2, -0.4}}]`? One question is if this is really the solution that is not good or if this is an issue of computing the derivative of the solution. But mesh refinement is a way to keep this at bay. The default mesh has about 20 elements. The mesh used is second order: `s1[[0]]["ElementMesh"]["MeshOrder"]`

Comment: @user21 There is a typo in your code it should be `D[χ[x], {x, 2}] == χ[x]^(3/2)/Sqrt[x]`

Comment: @AlexTrounev, fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @user21 Thank you! Now it looks better.

Answer (score 6):

There is also wavelet method for BVP. It is an example with Haar wavelets. It takes 0.36 s to solve this problem with 64 colocation points:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
L = 10; A = 0; B = 1; J = 5; M = 
 2^J; dx = (B - A)/(2 M); 
h1[x_] := Piecewise[{{1, A <= x <= B}, {0, True}}]; 
p1[x_, n_] := (1/n!)*(x - A)^n;
h[x_, k_, m_] := 
  Piecewise[{{1, 
     Inequality[k/m, LessEqual, x, Less, (1 + 2*k)/(2*m)]}, {-1, 
     Inequality[(1 + 2*k)/(2*m), LessEqual, x, Less, (1 + k)/m]}}, 0];
p[x_, k_, m_, n_] := 
  Piecewise[{{0, x < k/m}, {(-(k/m) + x)^n/n!, 
     Inequality[k/m, LessEqual, x, 
      Less, (1 + 2*k)/(2*m)]}, {((-(k/m) + x)^n - 
        2*(-((1 + 2*k)/(2*m)) + x)^n)/n!, (1 + 2*k)/(2*m) <= 
      x <= (1 + k)/
       m}, {((-(k/m) + x)^n + (-((1 + k)/m) + x)^n - 
        2*(-((1 + 2*k)/(2*m)) + x)^n)/n!, x > (1 + k)/m}}, 0];
xl = Table[A + l dx, {l, 0, 2 M}]; xcol = 
 Table[(xl[[l - 1]] + xl[[l]])/2, {l, 2, 2 M + 1}];
f2[x_] := 
 Sum[af[i, j] h[x, i, 2^j], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
  a0 h1[x]; 
f1[x_] := 
 Sum[af[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j, 1], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
  a0 p1[x, 1] + f10; 
f0[x_] := 
 Sum[af[i, j] p[x, i, 2^j, 2], {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}] + 
  a0 p1[x, 2] + f10 x + f00;
bc1 = {f0[0] == 1};
bc2 = {f0[1] == 0};
var = Flatten[Table[{af[i, j]}, {j, 0, J, 1}, {i, 0, 2^j - 1, 1}]];
varM = Join[{a0, f10, f00}, var];
eqq[x_] := Sqrt[x] f2[x]/L^(3/2) - f0[x]^(3/2);
eq = Flatten[Table[{eqq[x] == 0}, {x, xcol}]];
eqM = Join[eq, bc1, bc2];
sol = FindRoot[eqM, Table[{varM[[i]], 0.1}, {i, Length[varM]}], 
  MaxIterations -> 1000]; lst = 
 Table[{L x, Evaluate[f0[x] /. sol]}, {x, 0, 1, .01}];

ListLinePlot[lst, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Now we can compare with solution by xzczd `psol[d /. drule][r]`, here we show difference `f0[x]-psol[d /. drule][x]` And as we can see, combination of `ParametricNDSolveValue[]` and `FindRoot[]` is still good 
[image: Figure2]

Answer (score 5):

Thinking for a moment suggests `χ[10] == 0` is a numerically problematic boundary condition for two reasons: First, the `χ[x]^(3/2)` term, which means that `χ[x]` should not go negative or the integration will run into branch cut difficulties.  Second, the solution is concave up so that if it has a turning point (a positive minimum), it will increase; in fact, since the power `3/2` is greater than `1`, most solutions, if not all, will go off to infinity in finite time.  These in turn suggests starting the shooting method at the `x == 10` boundary condition, instead of the default lesser value `x == rin` chosen automatically by `NDSolve`.

```
rin = 10^-30;
sol = NDSolve[
   {Sqrt[x] D[χ[x], {x, 2}] == χ[x]^(3/2), χ[rin] == 1, χ[10] == 0},
   χ, {x, rin, 10}, PrecisionGoal -> 8, AccuracyGoal -> 8, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 20, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", 
     "StartingInitialConditions" -> {χ[10] == 0, χ'[10] == -1/100}}];

Chi[x_] := χ[x] /. sol[[1]]
Plot[Chi[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: It's a bit surprising that `WorkingPrecision -> 20` seems to be necessary to make `Shooting` method work.

Comment: @xzczd For reasons I can't fathom, the shooting method is varying `x` near `x == 0` instead of integrating to `x == rin`.  I'd think any programmer would understand that stepping outside the specified domain is inviting trouble.  You can fix it by using `Sqrt[x + $MinMachineNumber]` instead of `Sqrt[x]`, which won't make a difference if `x > 10^-292`, since `x + $MinMachineNumber` rounds to exact `x` in machine precision. It's a pretty ugly fix though.

Answer (score 3):

This is just to confirm @user21 result using Maple. I used `bvp[middefer]` (For BVP problem like this one) in Maple to get solution. I am not sure what this maps to in `NDSolve` now if any.

```
restart;
ode := diff(X(x),x$2)=X(x)^(3/2)/sqrt(x);
bc  := X(0)=1,X(10)=0;
sol := dsolve([ode,bc],X(x),`numeric`,method=bvp[middefer],abserr=0.001,maxmesh=8192*4);
plots:-odeplot(sol, x=0..10);
```

Similar (but not exact) looking solution is generated.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that Maple does not have FEM solver, only FDM.