# Having error with solving BVP problem

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-conditions

I am trying to solve [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/219593/overflow-with-ndsolve/219608#219608) differential equation but using my approach:

```
sol2[bc2_] := NDSolveValue[{χ''[x] == (χ^3/2)/Sqrt[x], χ[0] == bc2, χ[10] == 0},
χ, {x, 0, 10}];
χ2 = sol2[NMinimize[(bc2 - 1)^2, bc2][[-1, -1, -1]], {0, 1}]
Plot[{χ2[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

I got a wrong result
[image]

How can I implement my method correctly ? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code contains a few minor errors:

- The computation must start a tiny distance from`x = 0`, because the ODE is singular there.  (I used `x0 = 10^-8` but verified that the solution was insensitive to small changes.)
- Replace `χ^3/2` by `χ[x]^3/2` in the ODE.
- Delete `, {0, 1}` from second equation.

However, the main issue is that the solution is strongly dependent on the choice of `χ2'[x]` near `x == 0`.  Hence, the `Shooting` option must be employed explicitly, and a good guess given.

```
x0 = 10^-8;
sol2[bc2_] := NDSolveValue[{χ''[x] == (χ[x]^3/2)/Sqrt[x], χ[x0] == bc2, χ[10] == 0},
  χ, {x, x0, 10}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {χ'[x0] == -.85}}]
χ2 = sol2[NMinimize[(bc2 - 1)^2, bc2][[-1, -1, -1]]];
Plot[{χ2[x]}, {x, x0, 10}]
```

I obtained the guess for `χ'[x0] == -.85` by experimentation.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for an elegant solution. In my code for the NMinimize[(bc2 - 1)^2, bc2][[-1, -1, -1]], I don't know what is the purpose of [-1,-1,-1] ? Can you elaborate on that option ?

Comment: NMinimize returns `{0., {bc2 -> 1.}}`.  ` [-1,-1,-1]` extracts `.1`.  See the documentation for `Part`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey (+1) What is the reason for `NMinimize` in this code? It looks like method `"Shooting"` getting solution it self.

Comment: @AlexTrounev  You are correct that `NMinimize` serves no substantive purpose in the answer.  I retained it from the question, because I assumed that the OP planned to apply the code to a more challenging problem.

Comment: @bbgodfrey (+1) from me.

Comment: @bbgodfrey In what kind of BVP it could work?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  Perhaps, the OP had in mind a more complicated expression for `bc2` than `(bc2 - 1)^2`.  In any case, I wished to provide a solution using code that differed as little as possible from that in the question.