# Error when using NDSolve for $\epsilon y'' - y' + y^2 = 1$

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

Error when using NDSolve for $\epsilon y'' - y' + y^2 = 1$ with $0<x<1$ and $y(0) = \frac{1}{3}$, $y(1)=1$

My attempt:

```
Subscript[ϵ, 1] = 0.1;
Subscript[eqn, 1] = 
  NDSolve[{Subscript[ϵ, 1]*y''[x] - y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 1, 
    y[0] == 1/3, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}];
```

Error:

> NDSolve::ndsz: At x == 0.9005611463004037`, step size is effectively
> zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

However I see from this post https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3217456/697826 that it was numerically solved. What is wrong with my syntax?

---

Thank you to both of the submitted Answers. They are equally helpful!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your syntax. This is because

1. The default setting of `"Shooting"` method doesn't work well on this problem.
2. There's an arguable backslide of `"Shooting"` method around *v11*. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/130373/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/219656/1871) post for more info.

If you're in *v12.0* or higher, in which the nonlinear FEM solver is added, the simplest work-around is to turn to `FiniteElement`:

```
Subscript[ϵ, 1] = 0.1;
solfem = NDSolveValue[{Subscript[ϵ, 1]*y''[x] - y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 1, 
   y[0] == 1/3, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}, Method -> FiniteElement]

Plot[solfem[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

If you're before *v11*, then the following should work:

```
Subscript[ϵ, 1] = 0.1;
solshoot = NDSolveValue[{Subscript[ϵ, 1]*y''[x] - y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 1, 
   y[0] == 1/3, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"Shooting", 
    "StartingInitialConditions" -> {y'[1] == 1, y[1] == 1}}]

solshoot // ListPlot
```

[image]

Notice I've made use of an undocumented syntax of `ListPlot` here. See [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134222/1871) for more info.

Answer (score 13):

First, there are multiple solutions. Second, the one shown on math.SE has such a narrow range of feasible starting initial conditions fo $\epsilon = 1/10$ that the default shooting method in `NDSolve` is unlikely to find it, however the options are tweaked.  It's probably best to manually implement the shooting method.

```
\[Epsilon] = 1/10;
psol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{\[Epsilon]*y''[x] - y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 
    1, y[0] == 1/3, y'[0] == yp}, y, {x, 0, 1}, {yp}]

ypsol = FindRoot[psol[yp][1] == 1, {yp, -0.94, -0.93}, 
  Method -> "Brent"]

(*  {yp -> -0.93371}  *)

sol = psol[yp] /. ypsol
ListLinePlot@sol
```

[image]

Here's another form of the shooting method, which allows one to figure out the interval to pass to the Brent method above:

```
Manipulate[
 ListLinePlot@
  NDSolveValue[{\[Epsilon]*y''[x] - y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 1, y[0] == 1/3, 
    y'[0] == yp}, y, {x, 0, 1}],
 {yp, -0.95, -0.5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

Comment: Thank you Michael!

Comment: You're welcome, @Nalt! :)

Answer (score 3):

Things are easy to solve, if you differentiate one time.

```
e1 = 1/10;
eqs0 = {e1*y''[x] - y'[x] + y[x]^2 == 1, y[0] == 1/3, y[1] == 1}
deq1 = D[eqs0[[1]], x]

ic2 = First@First@Solve[eqs0[[1]] /. x -> 1, y'[1]] /. y[1] -> 1 /. 
         Rule -> Equal

ysol = y /. 
  First@NDSolve[{deq1, ic2, y[0] == 1/3, y[1] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}]

{ysol[0], ysol[1]}
(*   {0.333333, 1.00001}   *)

Plot[ysol[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]