# Solving a boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I have a problem solving a boundary layer problem with an infinity boundary conditions. I am almost there (I think). The problem is that, mathematica gives me this error:

> NDSolve: At  η  ==  6.53483 , step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

The system is exactly what I need  to solve, but maybe my shooting vaue is not correct or something else is wrong.

This is the graph that I should get. The graph is `F[η]` over `η` for different `n`:

[image]

I only try `n = 1.0` first, but still the shape of the graph is not even same. Can anyone help me?

This is my code:

```
inf = 20; 
sol = 
  NDSolve[
    {H'[η] == -2*F[η] - ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F'[η], 
     F[η]^2 - (G[η] + 1)^2 + (H[η] + ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F[η])*F'[η] ==  
       (F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 1)/2)*F''[η] + 
       F'[η]*((n - 1)*(F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 3)/2)*(F'[η]*F''[η] + G'[η]*G''[η])), 
     2*F[η]*(G[η] + 1) + (H[η] + ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F[η])*G'[η] == 
       (F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 1)/2)*G''[η] + 
       G'[η]*((n - 1)*(F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 3)/2)*(F'[η]*F''[η] + G'[η]*G''[η])),  
     F[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, H[0] == 0, F[inf] == 0, G[inf] ==- 1} /. n -> 1.0,
    {F,G,H}, {η, 0, inf}, 
    Method -> 
     {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> { F'[0]== 0.5,G'[0] ==-0.7}}];

Plot[Evaluate[{F[η]} /. sol], {η,0.00001,inf}, 
  PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

Comment: Have you seen this post? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57262/38575

Comment: Have you read this post?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104170/1871

Answer (score 6):

**Solution for n == 1**

As noted by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd), this problem is similar to that in [104170](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104170/1063), although more complicated.  The answer is easy to obtain for `n == 1`, if we happen to know good initial guesses for `F'[0]` and `G'[0]`.  For instance, using `{F'[0] == .510, G'[0] == -0.616}` immediately gives

[image]

The complete solution is

```
Plot[Evaluate[{F[η],G[η],H[η]} /. sol], {η, 0, inf}, PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}]
```

[image]

The question now becomes, how to obtain these good initial guesses.  Proceed as follows.  First, explicitly set `n == 1` in the second and third ODEs, solve for the second derivatives, and `Simplify`.

```
(Flatten@Solve[{F[η]^2 - (G[η] + 1)^2 + (H[η] + ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F[η])*F'[η] ==  
    (F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 1)/2)*F''[η] + 
    F'[η]*((n - 1)*(F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 3)/2)*(F'[η]*F''[η] + G'[η]*G''[η])), 
    2*F[η]*(G[η] + 1) + (H[η] + ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F[η])*G'[η] == 
    (F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 1)/2)*G''[η] + 
    G'[η]*((n - 1)*(F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 3)/2)*(F'[η]*F''[η] + G'[η]*G''[η]))}] 
    // Simplify) /. Rule -> Equal
(* {F''[η] == -1 + F[η]^2 - 2 G[η] - G[η]^2 + H[η] F'[η],
    G''[η] == 2 F[η] (1 + G[η]) + H[η] G'[η]} *)
```

Also, the first ODE reduces to

```
H'[η] == -2*F[η]
```

Next, derive alternative boundary conditions at large `η`.  This can be done by linearizing the equations about `F[η] == 0` and `1 + G[η] == 0`,

```
{F''[η] == H[η] F'[η], G''[η] == H[η] G'[η]}
```

Now, it is evident from the first ODE that `H` is approximately constant for large `η`, allowing the linearized equations to be integrated once (with constants of integration chosen so that `F'[η]` and `G'[η]` approach zero at large `η`.

```
{F'[η] == H[η] F[η], G'[η] == H[η] (G[η] + 1)}
```

The critical advantage of these new boundary conditions at `inf` is that they are valid for fairly small values of `inf`.  Combine these `n == 1` ODEs with the new boundary conditions and choose `inf == 5` to start.

```
inf = 5; 
sol = NDSolve[{H'[η] == -2*F[η] , 
    F''[η] == -1 + F[η]^2 - 2 G[η] - G[η]^2 + H[η] F'[η],
    G''[η] == 2 F[η] (1 + G[η]) + H[η] G'[η], 
    F[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, H[0] == 0, 
    F'[inf] == H[inf] F[inf], G'[inf] == H[inf] (G[inf] + 1)}, 
    {F, G, H}, {η, 0, inf}, Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" 
    -> {F[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, H[0] == 0, F'[0] == .5, G'[0] == -0.7}}];
Flatten@{F'[0], G'[0]} /. sol
(* {0.51028, -0.615914} *)
```

where the initial guess for `{F'[0], G'[0]}` are those in the question.  The result, immediately above, is a better set of initial guesses.  So, use them with `inf == 20`, yielding still better initial guesses (although the ones just above are good enough).

```
(* {0.510233, -0.615922} *)
```

which have hardly changed.  These are the values on which the initial guesses for the computation at the beginning of the answer are based.

**Solutions for various n (corrected)**

Solutions for other values of `n` can be obtained iteratively by using the initial guesses for `n == 1` for a slightly smaller value of `n`, and so forth.  However, `inf` must be somewhat larger to assure that `H[η]` is indeed constant near `η == inf` Start by defining

```
inf = 50;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{H'[η] == -2*F[η] - ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F'[η], 
    F[η]^2 - (G[η] + 1)^2 + (H[η] + ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F[η])*F'[η] == 
    (F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 1)/2)*F''[η] + F'[η]*((n - 1)*(F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 3)/2)
    *(F'[η]*F''[η] + G'[η]*G''[η])), 
    2*F[η]*(G[η] + 1) + (H[η] + ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F[η])*G'[η] == 
    (F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 1)/2)*G''[η] + G'[η]*((n - 1)*(F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 3)/2)
    *(F'[η]*F''[η] + G'[η]*G''[η])), 
    F[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, H[0] == 0, 
    F'[inf] == H[inf] F[inf], G'[inf] == H[inf] (G[inf] + 1)}, 
    {F, G, H, F', G'}, {η, 0, inf}, {n, Fp0, Gp0}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    {F[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, H[0] == 0, F'[0] == Fp0, G'[0] == Gp0}}];
```

Then, slowly decrease `n`, using the computed values of `{F'[0], G'[0]}` from a value of `n` as initial guesses for the next value of `n`.  It turns out that step in `n` must be quite small as `n` approaches 0.6.

```
guess = {0.510233, -0.615922};
Do[ans = Through[{F, G, H}[n, First@guess, Last@guess]] /. s;
    f[n] = First@ans;
    guess = D[Through[ans[η]], η][[1 ;; 2]] /. η -> 0;,
    {n, 1., .6, -.002}]
Plot[Evaluate@Through[Thread[f[n] /. n -> Range[1., .6, -.1]][η]], {η, 0, 20}, 
    PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y}, AspectRatio -> 5/7]
```

[image]

The total computation requires about 85 sec on my PC.

Comment: WOW!. I tried a very large number of initial guesses but no luck. Thanks for such a nice answer.

Comment: Thanks, @MMM.  I also tried many initial guesses without success until I used the alternative boundary conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me to solve this kind of question! :) I am very new to this, hence i can only manage to solve simple question, not this kind of question. However, may I know how do you plot G[n] and H[n] then? We cant simply change f[n] = First@ans to g[n] = First@ans; right? @bbgodfrey