# How to solve two different ode system which is related?

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

I need help on solving two systems which are related to each other. Basically, first I have to solve a non-linear ODE system. Then, I have to solve another system of equations, I have to ask mathematica to get the values from first system, in order to solve the second system.

The first system is this one:

```
inf = 50;
s = ParametricNDSolve[{H'[η] == -2*F[η] - ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F'[η], 
    F[η]^2 - (G[η] + 1)^2 + (H[η] + ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F[η])*F'[η] == 
    (F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 1)/2)*F''[η] + F'[η]*((n - 1)*(F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 3)/2)
    *(F'[η]*F''[η] + G'[η]*G''[η])), 
    2*F[η]*(G[η] + 1) + (H[η] + ((1 - n)/(1 + n))*η*F[η])*G'[η] == 
    (F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 1)/2)*G''[η] + G'[η]*((n - 1)*(F'[η]^2 + G'[η]^2)^((n - 3)/2)
    *(F'[η]*F''[η] + G'[η]*G''[η])), 
    F[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, H[0] == 0, 
    F'[inf] == H[inf] F[inf], G'[inf] == H[inf] (G[inf] + 1)}, 
    {F, G, H, F', G'}, {η, 0, inf}, {n, Fp0, Gp0}, 
    Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> 
    {F[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, H[0] == 0, F'[0] == Fp0, G'[0] == Gp0}}];
```

The value of F[η], G[η] and H[η] that I get from the first system will be used to solve the second system.

I believe there is a lot of mistakes i've done to solve the second question. Hence, I need help. thank you :)

This is the second system:

```
inf = 20; 
    alphabar=1;
    betabar=1;
    omegabar=0;
    R=1;
    sol =First@ NDSolve[{y1'[\[Eta]] == y2[\[Eta]] , 
y2'[\[Eta]]==(1/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*(H[\[Eta]]-((n - 1)*(F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 3)/2)*(F'[\[Eta]]*F''[\[Eta]] + 
                G'[\[Eta]]*G''[\[Eta]])))*y2[\[Eta]]+(1/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*(\[ImaginaryI]*R*(alphabar*F[\[Eta]]+betabar*G[\[Eta]]-omegabar)+F[\[Eta]])*y1[\[Eta]]-(2/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*(G[\[Eta]]+1)*y5[\[Eta]]+(R/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*F'[\[Eta]]*y3[\[Eta]]+\[ImaginaryI]*(R/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*alphabar*y4[\[Eta]],
y3'[\[Eta]]==-(\[ImaginaryI]*alphabar*(1/R))*y1[\[Eta]]-\[ImaginaryI]*betabar*y5[\[Eta]],
y4'[\[Eta]]==-((\[ImaginaryI]*R*(alphabar*F[\[Eta]]+betabar*G[\[Eta]]-omegabar)+H'[\[Eta]])/R)*y3[\[Eta]]-(H[\[Eta]]/R)*(-\[ImaginaryI]((alphabar*(1/R))*y1[\[Eta]]-\[ImaginaryI]*betabar*y5[\[Eta]]))-(1/R)*(((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2))*y3''[\[Eta]]+y3'[\[Eta]]*(n - 1)((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 3)/2))(F'[\[Eta]]* F''[\[Eta]]+ G'[\[Eta]]*G''[\[Eta]])),
y5'[\[Eta]]==y6[\[Eta]],
y6'[\[Eta]]==(1/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*(H[\[Eta]]-((n - 1)*(F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 3)/2)*(F'[\[Eta]]*F''[\[Eta]] + 
                G'[\[Eta]]*G''[\[Eta]])))*y6[\[Eta]]+(1/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*(\[ImaginaryI]*R*(alphabar*F[\[Eta]]+betabar*G[\[Eta]]-omegabar)+F[\[Eta]])*y5[\[Eta]]-(2/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*(G[\[Eta]]+1)*y1[\[Eta]]+(R/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*F'[\[Eta]]*y3[\[Eta]]+\[ImaginaryI]*(R/((F'[\[Eta]]^2 + G'[\[Eta]]^2)^((n - 1)/2)))*betabar*y4[\[Eta]],  y1[0] == 0, y2[0] == 0, y3[0] == 0, y4[0] == 0, y5[0] == 0, y6[0] == 0,y1[inf] == 0, y2[inf] == 0, y3[inf] == 0,y4[inf] == 0, y5[inf] == 0, y6[inf] == 0} /. n -> 1.0,
        {y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6}, {\[Eta], 0.00001, inf}];
```

This is the error:

```
 NDSolve
:Derivative order  1.  in term  y1
(1.)
[η]  should be a non-negative machine-sized integer.
```

Thank you so much if anyone can help me on this.

Attached is the system:

I replaced η with y, U with F, V with G and W with H.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The first part of this question is addressed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135325/1063).

Comment: Because all but the third ODE in the second block of code are first order, there should be only seven boundary conditions, not twelve.  Please specify which you wish to use.  Also, the fourth ODE contains `y3''[η]` as well as `y4'[η]`.  Is this correct?

Comment: Also, since these equations are linear and homogeneous in `y` the solution is zero.

Comment: Why don't you try to solve the two systems as a one system?

Comment: What is `i` in the 2nd system?

Comment: I would like to see the literature of the two systems. Is there any?

Comment: I have attached the original questions. I understand what u said, there should be 7 boundary conditions. But how should i choose? @bbgodfrey

Comment: i is complex number @MMM

Comment: Your `y4'[η]` Mathematica equation contains `y3''[η]` but the corresponding equation shown in the image does not.  Please check your code carefully for such errors.  Also, the set of six ODEs is linear in `y`.  With `y[0] == 0` for the six boundary conditions, the only solution is `y == 0` everywhere.

Comment: As you can see from the attached picture (the last term of `y4'[η]`), there is `D{μ*something here}`. If you look closely, the term 'something here' is actually `y3'[η] `(same thing). So if I have `D{μ*something here} = D{μ*y3'[η]}` meaning if we do product rule, we will get `uv'+vu'=μ*y3''[η]+y3'[η]*μ'`. That is why there exist `y3''[η].` @bbgodfrey

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the meaning of `D` in the picture.  It remains the case that the solution is identically zero for the given boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Here I will illustrate with a simple example to solve two couple systems of odes.

**Method I**

```
(*The first system*)
Ode1 = x'[t] == 1/y[t];    
Ode2 = y'[t] == x[t];    
ics := {x[0] == 1, y[0] == 2};
sys = Join[{Ode1, Ode2}, ics];    
soln = First@NDSolve[sys, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}];    
x1[t_] := Evaluate[x[t] /. soln]; (*assign the interpolating function x[t] to x1[t]*)    
y1[t_] := Evaluate[y[t] /. soln]; (*assign the interpolating function y[t] to y1[t]*)    
(*The second system*) 
Ode3 = x2'[t] == x1[t];
Ode4 = y2'[t] == x2[t] + y1[t] + y2[t];
ics2 := {x2[0] == -1, y2[0] == -2};
sys1 = Join[{Ode3, Ode4}, ics2];
soln1 = First@NDSolve[sys1, {x2, y2}, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[{x1[t], y1[t], {x2[t], y2[t]} /. soln1}, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

**Method II**

Solve the two systems as one,

```
Ode3 = x2'[t] == x[t];    
Ode4 = y2'[t] == x2[t] + y[t] + y2[t];    
combsys12 = Join[{Ode1, Ode2, Ode3, Ode4}, ics, ics2];    
combsoln = First@NDSolve[combsys12, {x, y, x2, y2}, {t, 0, 10}];    
Plot[{x[t], y[t], x2[t], y2[t]} /. combsoln, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]