# Unable to get numerical result by using Integrate/NIntegrate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

```
Nfunc[x_?NumericQ] := 
 E^(-x^2/2)/
   Sqrt[2*Pi]*(1/
      2 Erf[(x - 0.256048)/Sqrt[2*1.6^2 + 0.231313^2]/Sqrt[2]] - 
    1/2 Erf[-Infinity/Sqrt[2]])
nume = N[NIntegrate[x*Nfunc[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
   PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3], 4]
den = N[Normal[
   Integrate[Nfunc[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
    GenerateConditions -> False]], 4]
nume/den
```

I couldn't get numerator nor denominator. It keeps "executing" for hours. Is there a mistake or isn't mathematica able to perform this calculation?

I used functions with NumericQ for [speeding up calculation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197675/73740), but no luck.

EDIT: After restarting mathematica
[image: error]

Comment: Unchanged, your code executes in less than 1 second for me on MMA 12.1.0.  Maybe you need to start with a fresh kernel, or restart MMA.

Comment: @LouisB Now I got those errors https://i.imgur.com/HFAWZ1I.png

Comment: From the error message, it certainly looks like `Nfunc` already has a definition before its `SetDelayed`  ( `:=` ) definition.  Notice that the variable name is black instead of blue.  With a fresh kernel all undefined variable names are blue.  Two thoughts:  First, we usually don't begin a function name with a capital letter, but that is not the problem here.  Second, before defining a function we often execute a `Clear[ Nfunc ]` or  `ClearAll[ Nfunc ]` to eliminate conflicts like the one shown in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `Erf` can be difficult to work with, a simple, straightforward approach seems to work well:

```
ClearAll[Nfunc];
Nfunc[x_] := 
  E^(-x^2/2)/
    Sqrt[2*Pi]*(1/
       2 Erf[(x - 0.256048)/Sqrt[2*1.6^2 + 0.231313^2]/Sqrt[2]] - 
     1/2 Erf[-Infinity/Sqrt[2]]); (* why not -1 instead of Erf[]? *)

nume = NIntegrate[x*Nfunc[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  0.159712  *)

den = NIntegrate[Nfunc[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}]

(*  0.458961  *)

nume/den

(*  0.347986  *)
```

Looks right:

```
Plot[Nfunc[x], {x, -3, 3.7}, GridLines -> {{nume/den}, None}]
```

[image]